# jQuery: create object with values from two columns

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I am pretty new to objects and hope someone here can help me with this.

I have a table that looks as follows (reduced columns and rows for demo):

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1.</td><td>Item 1</td><td>10</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2.</td><td>Item 2</td><td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3.</td><td>Item 3</td><td>3</td>
        </tr>
        //...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a way I can create an object (array) using jQuery that contains all the values from columns 2 and 3 and returns something with the same look as the following ?
This would be needed with exactly the same layout, i.e. single quotes, commas and spaces.

```
[
    ['Item 1', 10],
    ['Item 2', 5],
    ['Item 3', 3],
    //...
]
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: Sure there is a way, what have you tried?

Comment: You'll just need to loop through the DOM, grab the values with `text()`, and build the array with `push`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not the best at Jquery either, but I would approach it like this:

```
var firstCol = []; 
var secondCol = [];

    $(document).ready(function () {

                    //GET values
                    $("#myTable tr:has(td)").each(function () {
                        var cell = $(this).find("td:eq(1)");
                        firstCol.push(cell.html());


                    });


                        $("#myTable tr:has(td)").each(function () {
                        var cell = $(this).find("td:eq(2)");
                        secondCol.push(cell.html());


                    });
          alert('From first column: ' + firstCol);
        alert('From second column: ' + secondCol);

     });
```

here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ydd53/)

**EDIT:** Hey Man, sorry took me so long... I have another solution for you, but again, i'm not a Jquery guru, so there might be a better way to do this. In fact, i'm quite sure of it. (Calling on better Jquery dudes to correct the code if it needs correcting :)

In anycase, here is a new [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ydd53/1/) for you.

Comment: This works, except for the formatting that I need, i.e. the quotes, commas and spaces.

Comment: Not at my computer at the moment, ill take a look soon :)

Comment: @user2571510 - I made a change to the fiddle an put it in the answer. Cheers! Mike

Comment: Thanks a lot. This looks exactly like what I need but here the rows are hard-coded, no ?

Comment: Well yes and no, the actually array builds dynamically, row by row until there are no more rows. Then to assign them to variables or whatever, I did that manually by selecting out of the array: Row[1] for example.

Answer (score 3):

```
var array = new Array();

$("#myTable tr").each(function(){ 
   array.push(new Array($(this).find("td:eq(1)").text(), $(this).find("td:eq(2)").text()));
});
```

Comment: This works, except for the formatting that I need, i.e. the quotes, commas and spaces.

Comment: What do you mean by formatting? It gets if there are commas, quotes ... in the td's content.

Answer (score 1):

I have not test this, but this is the idea:

```
var myAns = [];
$('#myTable tbody').each(function () {
    var row = $(this);
    var rowColumns = [];
    row.each(function (){
        rowColums.push($(this).html());
    })
    myAns.push(rowColumns);
});

//myAns should be in the format you want
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: How do I limit this so that it only grabs the data from columns 2 and 3, column 2 are the item names and column 3 the corresponding numbers ?